# A really simple question about heat transfer?

Tags: heat

In rectangular coordinates, the heat conduction vector can be expressed in terms of its components
$$\vec{\dot{Q_n}}=\dot{Q_x}\vec{i}+\dot{Q_y}\vec{j}+\dot{Q_z}\vec{k}$$
Please explain the meaning of this equation?

I know about vector! I know mathematics, but not this physics terms!

I know and don't know why you close my question since my issue is too simple to answer. Could any one see the difference between the concept of common vector and heat flux vector?

I had edited my ques again because I want it to open again.

Comment: Every vector can be decomposed on a basis. This particular decomposition means the same thing every other decomposition means.

Answer (score 2):

Flux is a vector quantity associated with the direction of heat transport.  The equation shows how the direction can be decomposed into cartesian components.

Do you understand how vectors work?

Comment: I thought one explain Fourier's law by a circular argument way. However, I know how vectors work.